# Create div in for loop with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating `<div>`s from a for loop based on user input. So if a user types 10 I want to create 10 `<div>`s with the text: `ITEM 1`, `ITEM 2`, `ITEM 3`, etc.

```
var select = $('#dropoptions').val();
var number = $('input').val(); 
$('.result').remove();
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += `<div class="result">ITEM ${select}</div>`; 
}
```

How can I add number in orders for the created `<div>`s?

Comment: What do you mean by "add number in orders for created div" ?

Comment: 1. where does container come from? 2. it's better to append your string into a variable then add it to the container after the loop. 3. number is a string. convert it to a number using `parseInt();`

Comment: when divs are created i want text inside the div to be for first div 1, second 2, third  3 etc @AurelBílý

Comment: If you wanted "Item {Number}" then you should be using `i` instead of `select`, eg `${i+1}`

Comment: Why do you not use the variable `i` (or `i + 1` for 1 ... n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `i` in your for loop to the string, like `'<div class="result">ITEM' + i + '</div>'`

```
var select = $('#dropoptions').val();
var number = $('input').val(); 
$('.result').remove();
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += '<div class="result">ITEM' + (i + 1) + '</div>'; 
}
```

Comment: @lejhbah you are welcome, consider accepting the answer, if it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. You need to make 2 changes:

1. Change `${select}` to (i+1)
2. `(i+1)` because it should start from 1 and not 0

```js
container = document.getElementById('container');
var number = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += '<div class="result">ITEM' + (i + 1) + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```